# Inverting the y-axis on a heatmap in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrBBS/) of a heatmap done in D3.js.

By default, the y-axis goes top down. I've had to invert the y-axis on line charts before [as described in this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/xVTaq9vfyIk).

However, I'm not quite sure how to do the required inversion here. Any ideas?

The relevant portions of my code (where the inversion would need to be applied) are as follows:

```
var xGrid = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, w - 2])
  .domain([0, data.influencer_range.length]);

var yGrid = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, h - 2])
  .domain([0, data.omm_range.length]);

var xOrdinal = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(data.influencer_range)
  .rangeBands([0, data.influencer_range.length]);

var yOrdinal = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(data.omm_range).
  rangeBands([0, data.omm_range.length]);

var x = function(point) {
  return point * xGrid(1);
};

var y = function(point) {
  return point * yGrid(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, as the Google thread instructs, swap the two y-range values: `.range([h - 2, 0])`

Similarly, your yOrdinal needs to be reversed: `.rangeBands([data.omm_range.length, 0])`

Finally, the reversal breaks your calculation of the height of a row (`yGrid(1)` is kinda hardcode-y, but oh well), so you need to adjust it too: `return point * yGrid(2)`

And there you have it: http://jsfiddle.net/qrBBS/2/

Comment: This seems to invert the x-axis for some reason.

Comment: From your code: `var row = xOrdinal(d[1]); var column = yOrdinal(d[0]);` is odd, bc row, which is y-ish is mapped to xOrdinal. So, instead of step 2 in my answer, if you reverse the range of `xOrdinal`, I think you get what you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/qrBBS/3/.